# Keeping two divs on a screen, no matter what the width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website that will have two divs, each on opposite sides of the site, and will adjust to a size that both fit on the screen. I tried making one div 70% and the other 25%, and theoretically that should work for no matter what the size, but it does slide down. I attempted to use absolute positioning, but that messed up my formatting, and im hitting a brick wall. Any help or tips are appreciated.

[Screen width of 500 px, both divs fit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpqJi.png)

[Screen width of 250 px, the right one slides down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u19XU.png)

Comment: Post your code, it's hard to debug images :-)

Comment: If your margins aren't percentage based, once the screen gets small enough, the divs will not stay beside each other. Either make sure your width and margins add up to no more than 100% (and be sure if you have padding, you're using `box-sizing: border-box`). If you want to keep your margins in a unit like px, you can set the div widths using `width: calc(70% - 20px)`, where 20px is the sum of your margins.

Comment: have you tried using Flexbox?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using inline-blocks, but is hard to know exactly what is going on without seeing your code. Try doing the following:

1. Try setting all margins to 0, including the body.
2. Make sure there is no white space (including spaces, tabs, or carriage returns) before the opening of each div or after the closing of each div. Extra spaces will throw things off.

For number 2, you can keep your structure and use comments so that white space is ignored.

```
<body><!--

--><div id="70percentdiv">


   </div><!--
   --><div id="30percentdiv">

   </div><!--
--></body>
```

Here I use the body element, but if you have other elements immediately before or after the divs utilize those ones instead. Again, it's hard to know exactly what is going on without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are more advanced CSS layouts nowadays, so you don’t need to resort to floating divs like you would have done in the early 2000s. Floats should be reserved for what they were [originally meant for](https://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/pdf/acm/advanced%20formatting/floating_blocks.aspx).

The following three options can be used to lay out content on a page. All 3 options are pure-CSS; no extra libraries or frameworks needed. You just have to watch out for browser support. Check out the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/) to learn more. I love this resource and I use it every single day.

The first option is to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Flexbox was built for one-dimensional layouts, e.g. a row of boxes, *although* the row may wrap to the next line if there isn’t enough space. (“Wrapping to the next line” doesn’t count as two-dimensional, since you cannot control where the line break occurs.) In your example, you have two boxes on a single row, so Flexbox is perfect.

```
<style>
  .row {
    display: flex;                  /* set up flexbox */
    flex-direction: row;            /* left-to-right flow */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;              /* prevent wrapping */
    justify-content: space-between; /* put all remaining space
      between the boxes, with no space on either end */
    align-items: stretch;           /* vertically stretch the boxes
      to fill the entire height of the row */
   }
  .box-main { flex: 1 1 70%; } /* suggest 70%, but allow flexibility */
  .box-side { flex: 1 1 25%; } /* suggest 25%, but allow flexibility */
  /* alternatively, if you don’t want any growing or shrinking, you can do:
  .box-main { flex: 0 0 70%; }
  .box-side { flex: 0 0 25%; } */
</style>
<div class="row">
  <main class="box-main">Main content lorem ipsum dolor ...</main>
  <aside class="box-side">Side content lorem ipsum dolor ...</aside>
</div>
```

One of the *many* advantages Flexbox has over floats is that you can change the order of the items, using only CSS (without having to change the markup/DOM). So you aren’t locked into which content goes on the "left" and which content goes on the "right". Moreover, “semantic” classnames like `.box-main` and `.box-side` are future-friendly: it would be silly to name the sidebar `.right` in the event you might want to move it to the left side of the page.

Another option is to use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), but **I would not recommend Grid for this particular situation**, since it is really meant for two-dimensional layouts. It is, however, possible, if not overkill.

```
<style>
  .grid {
    display: grid;                  /* set up grid */
    grid-template-columns: 70% 25%; /* define 2 columns, in this order */
    grid-template-rows: auto;       /* define 1 row, no specified height */
    grid-column-gap: 5%;            /* gap between columns */
  }
  /* that’s it! no need for classes on the boxes */
</style>
<div class="grid">
  <main>Main content lorem ipsum dolor ...</main>
  <aside>Side content lorem ipsum dolor ...</aside>
</div>
```

The third option is to use the [Multi-Column](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) layout, but it does not apply in your case since it requires all the columns to have the same width.